# Bootstrap 4: Dropdown Navtab does not work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Well I finally got Bootstrap 4 on my site, but it seems that it has some problems with drop down tabs. I tried by simply copying/pasting an example from bootstrap 4's official site:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs-with-dropdowns

But it does not work, even after I used JQuery to add dropdown toggle script. Strangely, if I replace it by Bootstrap 3, it will work normally. Anyone else having the same problem? Why is bootstrap 4's dropdown menu/tab not working?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, working example [mcve] as the code from the link you provided (when tested locally) works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Without code, it's a little harder to diagnose, but an issue that I came across is that I wasn't loading the drop down files locally.

I put this in the head and it did the fix.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```